# How do I remove Ubuntu, wipe hard drive and install Windows XP?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I have ubuntu 11.10, but i want to remove it, format my hard drive and install windows xp, but when i try doing this from the windows installer it says that the hard drive can't be formated so i would like to do it from the ubuntu installer without installing it again. Please help me
thanks.

Comment: Related (but probably not a duplicate, due to the specific needs here in terms of what problem has to be overcome): [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to do this is to probably create a new partition table on the drive from the Ubuntu live CD/DVD or USB flash drive. This is lower-level than just removing all the partitions.

1. Boot from the Ubuntu live CD/DVD or USB flash drive.
2. Select **Try Ubuntu** (not **Install Ubuntu**).
3. Run the GParted Partition Editor.

   - To do this, you can click the Ubuntu button at the upper-left corner, type in `gparted`, then click on the GParted icon when it comes up.
4. Make sure the proper drive is selected in the drop-down menu at the upper-right corner of the GParted window.

   - If you have other drives and the wrong one is selected, you can lose data on them! You do *not* want to create a new partition table on the wrong drive.
5. Click **Device** > **Create Partition Table...**.

   - *Make sure any important files on the drive have been put somewhere else, before doing this!*
6. Click OK in the window that comes up. (You can, and should, almost always stick with the default "MS-DOS" style of partition table.)
7. Quit GParted and reboot the system.
8. Install Windows on the newly "blank" disk.

[image: creating a new partition table in GParted]
The GParted window will look something like this, though not exactly like it.

Comment: When choosing the "MS-DOS" type (MBR) partition table, does it have to do with how Windows may prefer that, or is it just obsolete information now? If I knew Windows could handle a `GUID Partition table (GPT)`, then I would choose that, since it's more modern and more flexible... Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

> **Warning:** this will completely wipe your hard drive, so if you have any documents/data on the installed Ubuntu back them up to a USB first!

Assuming you have *only one hard drive*, and you want to remove Ubuntu 11.10 and format the drive, please do this:

1. Boot from the Ubuntu Installer/Live CD, and choose "Try Ubuntu..."
2. At the Live Desktop, press `Ctrl-Alt-T` to open a terminal.
3. In the terminal, type: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=8 && sync`
4. Shut-down the LiveCD.
5. Insert the Windows XP CD and start it; the XP installer should now detect the blank hard drive.

> Note: *If your computer is very old and uses IDE cables for the hard drives (wide connector), you may have to use `hda` instead of `sda`

Comment: At steps 3. / 4., I presume you need to wait until the `dd` command shows some sign of being completed?

Answer (score 0):

IF you don't care about wiping all the data off your hard drive and just want to start fresh with XP:

1. Boot into the Ubuntu live CD and run GParted.
2. Delete all the partitions.
3. Then, you can run the XP install.