# How to format entire HDD to it's factory condition?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, format

I tried to install an image onto a secondary HDD but wasn't able to make it work. Now I want to wipe out everything on the HDD to it's original factory condition so I can try again. I tried using Gparted but it still shows 4 different empty partitions. Any help on how I can bring it back to original factory condition is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This isn't really an answer. (I would have commented but do not have enough rep) This link is related and might help:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/162602/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-wipe-hard-drive-and-install-windows-xp
Mainly the steps 3 to 7 seem relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Just create a new partition table, and this will get rid of all the partitions. You can do this in Gparted by going to "Device" and then "Create Partition Table".

[image]